# How to use XCode to upload new files to a git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, xcode5

I have added a file from the filesystem to XCode project.
Now when I push the project to my github repository, this file doesn't seem to be uploaded.

What am I missing ?

Comment: How exactly do you do the 'push'.  Is it a button?  What do you do in the IDE to do the equivalent of a add (git requires an 'add' before it actually does a 'commit', so I'm not sure what the IDE is/will show).

Comment: Maybe a forum or mailing list about XCode would be a better place to ask....

Answer (score 1):

When dragging files into an XCode project, you have to check: `[X] Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)` otherwise, files are just referenced in the project settings, but not actually copied inside the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your added file is `mynewsource.cc`, did you run the

```
 git add mynewsource.cc
```

command (to add the file into GIT repository), then the

```
 git commit -a
```

command (to commit the addition and other changes; this probably would fire some `$EDITOR` to have you edit some commit message), and finally

```
 git push
```

to push (i.e. forward) the changes to the upstream git server?

I strongly suggest to look at [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/documentation); it has very well written tutorials and short videos

Adding a file to some IDE's (e.g. Xcode) project is unrelated (and should be unrelated) to version control (like `git` or `svn`). Perhaps your IDE should have some way (menu entries....?) to add a new file to version control (GNU `emacs` VC mode has one).

Comment: I'm new to git, right now I'm just using the XCode interface.

Comment: But as I try to explain, `git` and `XCode` are totally unrelated (like apples and fishes are). And please look at `git` tutorial and video, they are very understandable and newbie-friendly.

Comment: I'm a command line user myself... however this user is using an IDE so would like to know how they can check in the IDE itself.  Let me update the title a bit in fact.